# PHP: Access a variable outside the scope of its closure

Tags: php, closures, scope

Is there a way to access a variable from a closure outside the closure? For instance, I want to access `$wallet` outside the closure:

```
public function generate()
{
    $this->ssh->run([
        '~/Web/gatewayd/gateway generate_wallet'
    ], function($line) use ($fn)
    {
            $wallet = data $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    return json_decode($wallet);
}
```

I tried this solution, but I feel that this is neither working or a good practice:

```
public function generate()
{
    $wallet = null;
    $this->ssh->run([
        '~/Web/gatewayd/gateway generate_wallet'
    ], function($line) use ($wallet)
    {
            $wallet = $line;
    });

    return json_decode($wallet);
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just try with:

```
public function generate()
{
    $wallet = null;

    $this->ssh->run([
        '~/Web/gatewayd/gateway generate_wallet'
    ], function($line) use ($fn, &$wallet)
    {
            $wallet = data $line.PHP_EOL;
    });

    return json_decode($wallet);
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the ideal solution would be if `$this->ssh->run()` would *return* the return value of the callback function. I.e.:

```
$wallet = $this->ssh->run(..., function ($data) { return $data; });
```

Lacking that, the best you could do is `use` with a reference:

```
$this->ssh->run(..., function ($data) use (&$wallet) { $wallet = $data; });
                                           ^
echo $wallet;
```